# Weighting data and causal modelling

Tags: causality, survey, difference-in-difference, propensity-scores, weights

When using causal models such as difference-in-difference or propensity score matching, will weighting the data to represent the population effect the outcome (i.e., will it bias my results)?

Comment: Indeed, see https://gking.harvard.edu/files/abs/cem-plus-abs.shtml